# Use household power strip for 12V/24V power

Tags: voltage, power, dc, 12v, dimmer

I have a 12V/24V dimmer (rated 60W) and need to hook up 8 different lights, can I just use a regular power strip to distribute the 12V/24V? the power strip of course says 230V on it, but does it function right with 1/10th of that?

Comment: Don't use plugs and sockets designated for mains for other voltages. Someone will plug one of your low-voltage devices into a mains socket.

Comment: yeah I mean obviously I would't put the lights into the actual wall socket, just the power strip when it's on the dimmer 12V/24V. I just need something to split the dimmer output and I already have a power strip with switch and led and everything so why get seperate new 12V stuff for it if that can work with less power...I'm not going to give this to anybody else

Comment: Nothing is obvious from your question which isn't very well written. You can [edit] to improve it. Draw a diagram of what you are proposing. Remember that you're on an international site and there is no location information in your question or in your user profile. Words like "power strip" mean different things in different countries.

Comment: *How do you know* you won't put the lights into an actual wall socket?  **That is the obvious thing to do**.  Anyone will do it - including others in your house, and yourself after you forget.

Comment: @HelpImStupid One more thing to consider is that a power strip is usually rated for one current. For example, in the US often this is \$15\:\text{A}\$. But not necessarily. Even assuming you want to just ignore the advice against using mains outlets for DC for safety reasons, the wiring in the power strip can be absolutely scarily "thin" and flimsy. (I should show you a picture of one I have here, had I the time.) AC also self-extinguishes arcs, while when you plug in your DC devices the arcing will be excessive compared to design intent. And for the same power, your DC will require more amps.

Comment: @HelpImStupid Usually I want to down-rate the current by a factor of 5 or so if going to DC and considering plug-in/unplug events. That might just barely fit a 15 A strip, as 60/24 is about 2.5 A and 15 A/5 is about 3 A. Well, so technically it may work. But read the rest of the advice. Obviously, you are in control of your own situation and none of us can do anything about it except suggest some thoughts to you.

Answer (score 11):

It will *function*, but **using standard plugs and sockets for the wrong voltage is a *spectacularly* bad idea**.   This relies on you being in total control, remembering everything about your setup forever, and making no blunders...

Every novice goes "oh, I can handle that"...  *but that is simply not realistic*, and the standards bodies who set electrical safety rules *know that* which is why they do not allow it.

Most 230V appliances won't do much if plugged into a 12/24V source... the bigger problem is the reverse, nothing keeps anyone from plugging your 12/24V light into an AC mains socket and starting a fire, or killing someone if the light is not up to the standards required to handle 230V safely.

You should use whatever connector standards exist in your country for the voltage you are handling.  There are many such standards for 12V.  For 24V, you may need to improvise something with electronics-supply-house connectors.  As long as it's far away from any conflicting standards, that should be fine. Nothing from the AC mains parts bin should be used for this, despite how easy it is.

Or heck, you can simply merge a gob of wires on a terminal block.  That is better than using incompatible connectors.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this multiple times. Your answer probably saves people from serious pain.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that many switches and relays, though I'm not sure I've seen it on connectors, have a minimum voltage/current as well. The contacts oxidize, and you can get high contact resistance until enough current flows, or more usually a spark happens, to break the oxide layer and lower the contact resistance.